# NSDictionary returns nil for NSNumber

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, gamekit, nsnumber

I'm using gamekit to send an nsnumber in an nsdictionary. When I NSlog the Dictionary the number is ok but when I try and get an NSNumber it is always (null).

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver  unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSNumber *receivedHostNum = (NSNumber*)[dict objectForKey:@"h"];
if (gameStarted == NO){

    NSLog(@"%@",dict);
    NSLog(@"My Num:%i",[hostNum intValue]);
    NSLog(@"%@",receivedHostNum);
    NSLog(@"Recieved Num:%i",[receivedHostNum intValue]);

    if ([hostNum intValue]>[receivedHostNum intValue])
        NSLog(@"You are host");
    else
        NSLog(@"You are client");
}
```

This is the log:

```
2012-08-21 14:34:06.067 PeerPicker[6667:c07] {
    "-589267889" = h;
}
2012-08-21 14:34:06.068 PeerPicker[6667:c07] My Num:-2142897577
2012-08-21 14:34:06.068 PeerPicker[6667:c07] (null)
2012-08-21 14:34:06.069 PeerPicker[6667:c07] Recieved Num:0
2012-08-21 14:34:06.069 PeerPicker[6667:c07] You are client
```

Comment: When is the value for h being inserted into the dictionary? Mind posting that code in comments? The reason for it is that it looks like there is a key "-589267889" for object h, but no object for key h.

Comment: No. That's totally wrong and I definitely didn't put the key and the object the wrong way round when I created the NSDictionary. Don't be silly :p PS Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you have put your number in your dictionary the wrong way. Your log shows:

```
2012-08-21 14:34:06.067 PeerPicker[6667:c07] {
    "-589267889" = h;
}
```

It should be:

```
2012-08-21 14:34:06.067 PeerPicker[6667:c07] {
    "h" = -589267889;
}
```

You have inverted the key and the object when constructing your array or when storing it.